# Deserialize post request

Tags: c#, json

im trying to deserilize this code on Windows Forms with C#, and i need to insert on a table the "response" foreach register, but i dont know how to access to every response section.

```
[
{
    "error": false,
    "code_error": 0,
    "error_message": null,
    "response": {
        "cp": "83240",
        "asentamiento": "Fuentes Del Mezquital",
        "tipo_asentamiento": "Colonia",
        "municipio": "Hermosillo",
        "estado": "Sonora",
        "ciudad": "Hermosillo",
        "pais": "México"
    }
},
{
    "error": false,
    "code_error": 0,
    "error_message": null,
    "response": {
        "cp": "83240",
        "asentamiento": "Las Quintas",
        "tipo_asentamiento": "Colonia",
        "municipio": "Hermosillo",
        "estado": "Sonora",
        "ciudad": "Hermosillo",
        "pais": "México"
    }
},
```

]

the provider gave me this code, and if you see in the code below only open the console in case that an error occours. but in the else clausule i need to access in the response to get the params for each register.

```
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string endpoint_sepomex  = "http://api-sepomex.hckdrk.mx/query/";
        string method_sepomex = 'info_cp/';
        string variable_string = '?type=simplified';
        string url = endpoint_sepomex + method_sepomex + variable_string;
        
        var response = new WebClient().DownloadString(url);
        dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response);
        
        foreach(var i in json)
        {
            if(i.error)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Algo salio mal");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Todo salio bien");
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    
    
}
```

}

Comment: consider using a strongly typed model and classes.

Comment: Put something like `Console.WriteLine(i.response.cp);` then. They're just properties, access them like any object property. (Although it would be clearer and easier if you used a strongly typed model, as suggested above).

Answer (score 1):

You would want to create a model. You can use a site like [Json2CSharp](https://json2csharp.com/) to help with the process:

```
public class Response    {
    [JsonProperty("cp")]
    public string Cp { get; set; } 

    [JsonProperty("asentamiento")]
    public string Asentamiento { get; set; } 

    [JsonProperty("tipo_asentamiento")]
    public string TipoAsentamiento { get; set; } 

    [JsonProperty("municipio")]
    public string Municipio { get; set; } 

    [JsonProperty("estado")]
    public string Estado { get; set; } 

    [JsonProperty("ciudad")]
    public string Ciudad { get; set; } 

    [JsonProperty("pais")]
    public string Pais { get; set; } 
}

public class BaseResponse    {
    [JsonProperty("error")]
    public bool Error { get; set; } 

    [JsonProperty("code_error")]
    public int CodeError { get; set; } 

    [JsonProperty("error_message")]
    public object ErrorMessage { get; set; } 

    [JsonProperty("response")]
    public Response Response { get; set; } 
}
```

Then you can deserialize like so:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<BaseResponse>>(response);
```